# How to programmaticaly get the AutoRecover Path of a Workbook?

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vsto

Hallo People,

i'm trying to get the Autorecover Path a Workbook. I have see this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.autorecover.aspx) on MSDN but there is no example to see how this work!!

Can someone show me how this work?

Thank you!

Comment: i found it : string recoveryPath = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AutoRecover.Path;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just

```
Application.AutoRecover.Path
```